# ffmpeg - Stream webcam - RTP h264 + audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, h.264

I am trying to create a rtp stream using ffmpeg. I am taking input from my logitech C920 which has built in h264 encoding support and also has a microphone. I wanted to send both video(h264 either with the built in encoder or ffmpeg's encoder) and audio(any encoding) through RTP and then play the stream using ffplay.

So far I am able to send only the video with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -r 24 -video_size 320x240 -c:v libx264 -f  rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:9999
```

and also the audio separately using the command:

```
ffmpeg  -f alsa -i plughw:CARD=C920,DEV=0 -acodec libmp3lame -t 20 -f  rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:9998
```

and play the sdp file with:

```
 ffplay -i -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp test3.sdp 
 ffplay -i -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp test4.sdp
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

How can I play the two streams with a single ffplay command as ffplay cannot take two inputs and I can't send two streams using a single RTP stream(or can I?).
Also, how can I use the built in h264 encoder of my webcam?

Thank you!